# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm new to Android, but already created a quite big app. I was working with SharedPreferences and then got this error. I got rid of all lines about SharedPreferences, but still get same eror. I cant get where I shoud look for this #63 line... help me please. If you need some other lines of code, please ask.

> 03-01 01:21:28.146  29762-29762/com.example.puzzle.app
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main`enter code here`
>       Process: com.example.puzzle.app, PID: 29762
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.puzzle.app/com.example.puzz
>
> le.app.PlayActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file
>   line #63: Error inflating class 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class 
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)
>               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)
>               at com.example.puzzle.app.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:84)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>   ......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:focusable="false">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:onClick="FindClicked" android:background="@drawable/one" android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                />
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:text="2" android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:onClick="FindClicked"
                android:textSize="45sp" android:textColor="#292929"
                android:background="@drawable/two"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn1" android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:text="3" android:id="@+id/btn3" android:onClick="FindClicked"
                android:background="@drawable/tree" android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn2"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/four" android:textSize="45sp" android:textColor="#292929"
                android:text="4" android:id="@+id/btn4" android:onClick="FindClicked"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn3"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/five"
                android:text="5" android:id="@+id/btn5" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn1" android:textSize="45sp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn1"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/six"
                android:text="6" android:id="@+id/btn6" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn5" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn2"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp" 
android:background="@drawable/seven"
                android:text="7" android:id="@+id/btn7" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn6" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn3"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp" 
android:background="@drawable/eight"
                android:text="8" android:id="@+id/btn8" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn5" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn4"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/nine"
                android:text="9" android:id="@+id/btn9" android:onClick="FindClicked"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn5" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn5" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn5" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp" 
android:background="@drawable/ten"
                android:text="10" android:id="@+id/btn10" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn9" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn6"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/eleven"
                android:text="11" android:id="@+id/btn11" android:onClick="FindClicked"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn10" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn7" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn7"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/twelve"
                android:text="12" android:id="@+id/btn12" android:onClick="FindClicked"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn11" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn8" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn8"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/thirteen"
                android:text="13" android:id="@+id/btn13" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn9" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn9"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn9" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/fourteen"
                android:text="14" android:id="@+id/btn14" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn13" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn10"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn10"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/fiveteen"
                android:text="15" android:id="@+id/btn15" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn14" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn11"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn11"/>
        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/sixteen"
                android:text="0" android:id="@+id/btn16" android:onClick="FindClicked" android:textSize="45sp"
android:textColor="#292929"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn15" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn12"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn12"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn1" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn2" android:layout_marginRight="13dp" android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ugol_1"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp" android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                   android:background="@drawable/ugol_2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn4"
                   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn4" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn4"
android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp" android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                   android:background="@drawable/ugol_4"
                   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn16" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn16"
                   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn16" android:layout_marginTop="13dp" android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp" android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                   android:background="@drawable/ugol_3"
                   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn13" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn2"  android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                   android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn2" />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/txtTimer"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn1" android:layout_marginTop="31dp"  android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
android:textSize="25sp"
                android:onClick="HideTimerAndNubOfMoves"
                android:clickable="true" android:text="00:00:00"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="0000"
                android:id="@+id/txtNumOfMoves"
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4" android:textSize="25sp"
                android:onClick="HideTimerAndNubOfMoves"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtTimer" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRestart"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnRestart" android:layout_marginRight="27dp"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnSmallExit"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_smallexit"
                android:onClick="GoToMenu"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:id="@+id/btnRestart"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_smallrestart"
                android:onClick="Restart" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSmallExit"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSmallExit" android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSmallExit"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the XML layout file that you are inflating in `PlayActivity`

Comment: it is really hard to help without seeing the code that caused the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using too many `ImageView`s and `Button`s in your `PlayActivity`'s layout. You seem to be taking the background images for all of them from your `res/drawable` directory.

Here is what you can try:

- Add the `android:largeHeap=“true”` attribute to the `application` tag
  in your project's manifest file.
- Resize your images with a graphics editor and reduce their size & dimension.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. Helped!Hope that edding SharedPreferences will not ruin it again!